# Error: cannot convert 'double (*)[(order + -1)]' to 'double (*)[100]

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing a code to find the determinant of a given matrix after reading it from a text file which has the same format of providing the data about the matrix.
Here is a sample of the matrix.txt file:

---

3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

---

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
#define N 100
double det (double mat [N] [N], int order);

int main ()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open ("matrix.txt");
    int n;
    double readMatrix [N][N];
    fin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fin >> readMatrix [i][j];
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << det(readMatrix, n) << endl;;


    return 0;
}

double det (double mat [N] [N], int order)
{
    double coff [order - 1][order - 1];
    double delta = 0;

    if (order == 2)
    {
        return ((mat[0][0])*(mat [1][1]) - (mat [0][1])*(mat [1][0]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < order; k++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                coff [k-1][j] = mat [k][j];
            }
            for (int j = k + 1; j < order; j++)
            {
                coff [k-1][j-1] = mat [k][j];
            }
        }

        delta += (pow(-1, i) * mat[0][i] * det( coff, order - 1 ));
    }
    return delta;
}
```

I am getting error in `delta += (pow(-1, i) * mat[0][i] * det( coff, order - 1 ));`. This is the error **Error: cannot convert 'double (*)[(order + -1)]' to 'double (*)[100]**. I looked up the internet but people who got this error were generally making the same mistake of passing the size of the array in the function i.e. function(array [n]).

Comment: Variable-Length Array is not supported in the standard C++. You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: `double coff [order - 1][order - 1];` is not valid C++. Do you know `std::vector`? Using that will be much easier.

Comment: `double coff [order - 1][order - 1]` defines a variable of a type different from `double[N][N]`. Whereas `det` expects a parameter of type `double[N][N]`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `double (*)[N]`, since it is a parameter.

Comment: `pow(-1, i)` is a very bad way to get alternate sign. Use `i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1` instead